# Visual Studio 2015 use Ctrl-Enter instead of Tab

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012 (VB) I used Ctrl-Enter to complete Intellisense suggestions. I just installed VS 2015 and now Ctrl-Enter is not working, now I need to use the Tab key. Ctrl-Enter inserts a new line above current. It's hard to study for new keyboard layout. How to return my lovely Ctrl-Enter?

Thanks.

Comment: It appears that CTRL+ENTER is assigned to another task. You would need to go into tools, options, keyboard then select edit.completeword, set up CTRL+ENTER should then show what CTRL+ENTER is assigned to, that assignment needs to be deleted first. If you try this and still no luck you might need to reset setting in Visual Studio or use import/export settings first.

Comment: Anything that you suggest does'nt help, sorry. What can I try else?

Comment: I would had recommended another solution if I had one, sorry but that's it. You might submit this to this site https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback

Comment: You can probably change this in the Keyboard settings. Tools -> Settings -> Environment -> Keyboard.

Comment: I have the same issue here. Changing CTRL+ENTER to Edit.CompleteWord doesn't work either: It just does nothing. Still, that's better than taking me away from where I was typing and inserting a line above.

Answer (score 0):

Took forever but I found it!

Under **Options -> Environment -> Keyboard** the command is **Edit.BreakLine**.

You can add a global shortcut or just texteditor shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This was driving me nuts!